# Existence of Periodic Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

I'm working with the system of equations below that represents a Pendulum with constant forcing. 
\begin{align*}
\theta'&=v\\
v'&=-bv-\sin(\theta)+k
\end{align*}
Where $\theta$ gives the angular position, $v$ is the velocity, $b>0$ measures the damping force and $k\geq0$ the applied torque.

The question ask, Suppose $k>1$ Prove that there exist a periodic solution for this system.

My original idea was to use the Poincaré-Bendixon theorem in our book which says that if $\Omega$ is a closed, and bounded limit set of a planar system of differential equations that contains no equilibrium point. Then $\Omega$ is a closed orbit.

If we look at the $v$ nullcline, we can see that the vector field in the region above (say when $v=v_2$) points downwards. Above (say when $v=v_1$) it points upwards.

We also know that when $k>1$ there are no longer any equilibrium points.

But...this version of the Poincaré-Bendixon theorem is used for planar systems, where I guess in this problem we are working on a cylinder. Is there another way to look at this question, or a different theorem to use. Any help would be great!

Comment: The Poincare-Bendixson theorem holds for plane, cylinder or sphere.

Comment: yes, thats true. But this specific theorem is formulated for a planar surface. I've tried to find theorems related to 2 dimensional manifolds but a lot of them use terminology and ideas that are above my head. I was hoping to find a way around that.

Comment: The Bendixon-Poincare theorem is verbatim the same for the cylinder as for the plane. This is because the Jordan closed curve theorem holds: any closed continuous curve without self-intersections divides the phase space into two domains, inside and outside. It is those 2-manifolds (such as torus) produce problems, for which the Jordan theorem does not hold.